# MVC controller's string[] parameter is null when posting JSON data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I post data with jQuery but I have a problem with array data. The values supplied to the MVC controller are always null.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
 var FilterCategory = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();
 var posting = $.post(url, { cursorid: lastid, CatFilter: FilterCategory });
```

The form data from the network:

```
cursorid:5434cdc84ba4dd0c40396851
Filter[]:1
Filter[]:3
Filter[]:4
```

Here's the C# side:

```
public ActionResult GetDataTweets(string cursorid,string[] CatFilter)
    {
       bla bla
    }
```

cursorid has a value, but CatFilter is null.

What do I need to do to have the correct value supplied to CatFilter?

Answer (score 1):

This code here:

```
var posting = $.post(url, { cursorid: lastid, CatFilter: FilterCategory });
```

From MVC's perspective it's sending a class, so you need a reciprocal C# class to package the data.
Create a class to handle that data, for example:

I am assuming your CatFilter array is a string array:

```
public class Data{
  public string cursorid { get; set;}
  public string[] CatFilter {get; set;}
}
```

Then change your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetDataTweets(Data data)
{
   var s1 = data.cursorid;
   var s2 = data.CatFilter[0];
}
```

if CatFilter is a class then you'd need to create a CatFilter class to map to the javascript version.